# Torsion equivariant cohomology of reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, reductive-groups, equivariant-cohomology

Let $G$ be a reductive group with maximal torus $T$. One knows that the equivariant cohomology ring of a point with rational coefficients is $\mathbb{Q}[X^*(T)]^W$, and also there is an equivariant Kunneth formula

$$
 H^*_G(X \times Y) = H_G^*(X) \otimes_{H_G^*(pt)} H_G^*(Y)
$$

Now suppose we instead take coefficients in a field $k$ with positive characteristic $\ell$. Under what condition on $\ell$ does the above story still go through? (I expect $\ell \nmid W$ is good enough, but can one do better?).

Comment: Here is a somewhat related MO post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324826/borels-presentation-for-the-cohomology-of-a-flag-variety

Comment: Actually, a more relevant answer is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440691/koszul-duality-and-operatornamehbg-concise-proof/440716#440716  You can use the computation of cohomology of $G/T$ (which is homotopic to $G/B$) with coefficients of arbitrary characteristic and the computation of the cohomology of $BT$ to write down a spectral sequence that converges to the cohomology of $BG$.

Comment: I see that $H^*(G/T)$ and $H^*(BT)$ are even. But in the spectral sequence $H^*(BG, H^*(G/T)) \implies H^*(BT)$, but I guess this doesn't immediately rule out $H^*(BG)$ having odd terms that cancel.

Comment: Yes indeed.  You have to prove a special property of the transgressions.